# Symfony: display image in update view

Tags: php, symfony

I have built a form that contains input type file field. I Want to display attached image in update action. However, in insert mode I want to display only input type file field.

Here is function that build my custom form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name', 'text', array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
        ->add('photo', 'file', array('data_class' =>  null, 'required' => false, 'property_path' => getFoto()))
        ->setMethod("POST")              
    ;
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'MyProject\MyByndle\Entity\Premio'
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Form Type Extension, extending the File field type.

You have an example on the symfony documentation [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_form_type_extension.html), that answers what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks for suggest.
I've follow all steps but application return this error:
"Variable "image_url" does not exist in (twig)".

I've declared service in MyBundle/Resources/config/service.xml
It's the right way?

Comment: Please add some code so i can check what you did and how you did.

Comment: Solved. Problem was in twig, i've forgot to create override form type.